# Display undefined variable name not just undefined node

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I realise this is a slightly silly question but I was wondering if there was a way to display the actual name of the variable that is defined rather than just

```
 Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
      at Object.gamesExport.addGame (/var/www/football.co.uk/app/api/api.Games.js:104:88)
```

In this particular case I'm scrapping data and its very difficult/boring to work out which one is missing. I know it also gives me the line and character so i can look it up like that, but I'm lazy...

I know that firebug has this feature:
[image]

So it must be possible with node as well

I'm using node 6.3.0

Comment: You can't open a text editor, enter a line number and then read it?  You could have done it 20 times in the time it took to ask this ridiculous question.  You should know better, with the number of points you've got.

Comment: No comments but down votes? A little feedback guys

Comment: As I said Archer... I could, but I don't want to.

Comment: This will not be answered.

Comment: So we should just **GUESS* what's happening at line 104? We're good, but not THAT good. Our magic crystal balls are all in the shop for service, so we can't read your mind.

Comment: The variable is undefined. Isn't that enough information? I'm not asking to fix the issue :) I'm asking to display the variable name.

Comment: We know what you're asking.  We took the time to read your question.  Read the file where the error is.

Comment: :O why are is there aggression in your characters @Archer I appreciate everybody taking the time to read. But I am genuinely confused why this is badly received. I wouldn't have thought its that bad a thing. It clearly is, but wouldn't this be something difficult/fun to build?

Comment: What have you tried?  Post the code that you've already tried and explain what went wrong.

Comment: For example firebug display the variable name, but google chrome does not. I've always found this annoying.

Comment: I have no idea where to start @Archer this is why I've asked :) I always try to fix these things myself, however this time I really have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [stack-trace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-trace) you can quickly get the line and file from your stack then feed them into `readline`. Its pretty sloppy but I think it solves your problem.

```
var stackTrace = require('stack-trace');
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

try{
   var x = 1;
   x = 1+y; //Error Y not defined
}catch (err){
   var count = 0;
   var trace = stackTrace.parse(err)
   var eFile = trace[0].fileName
   var eLine = trace[0].lineNumber

   var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream(eFile)
   });

   rl.on('line', function(line) {
      count++
      if (count === eLine) {
        console.log("Error: "+line)
      }
   });

}
```

Comment: Thank you woodsy for doing this :) So I'll just need to make this global in my express app and then all errors will be caught and it will let me know the line number. I'll study this either way to understand more about it.